# how to customize access denied page sharepoint 2016

Tags: html, access-denied, sharepoint-2016

I am looking to find a solution to brand "access denied page" in sharepoint 2016.

The sharepoint default page is simple and I want to brand this page, also having my company logo.

Below is the image of the default page in sharepoint 2016.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SharePoint power shell console to set them.
Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage

Example

```
Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage -Identity AccessDenied -RelativePath "/_layouts/custompages/myaccessdenied.aspx" -WebApplication "http://server_name/mywebapp"
```

Source https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607768.aspx Can still be used in Sharepoint 2016.